# setInterval and clearInterval. Smth went wrong

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

So, I have initialized my var with setInterval.
I want to stop and to start it. And I wish to have this control as often as I would like to.
This is the code

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
function myStartFunction() {
    setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    //setInterval(myVar, 1000);
}
</script>
```

jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g8jmccfu/1
I press "Hold" button and it's works nice. Then I click "Continue" and this works nice too. And then I click "Hold" again... and it doesn't work.
I'd like appreciate any help and any suggestions.

Comment: JSFiddle changes the scope of the JS window, so it's no longer global. You just have to change the setting to "no wrap..." -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g8jmccfu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to reassign the new timer ID to `myVar` (which I called `interval`):

```
var interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    // ...
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
function myStartFunction() {
    interval = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
}
```

Your variable still contained the ID of the old interval, which made `clearInterval(myVar)` do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, you need to define a variable

```
   var myVar;
    function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
    }

    function myStartFunction() {
        myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
    }

    myStartFunction();

    function myStopFunction() {
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
```